# parsing HTML tags coming from a json response text

Tags: jquery, html, json

I have a jQuery function that calls a 3rd party web service. The 3rd party web service returns a json response. I am binding a DIV element's text property in my HTML page to an elements from the json response.

All this works fine. For brevity I have excluded the entire code.

jQuery
    success: function (data) 
    {
        $('#level2').text(data.data.content);
    }

HTML

```
<div id="level2"> </div>
```

However, the json response output has HTML tags in them,

Example

```
<h2>Header 2</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel lacinia nulla.<p>
```

How do I ensure the html tags are parsed by the browser and the text is displayed as a browser would render it, like below,

### Header 2

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras vel lacinia nulla.

Please help.

Comment: Do as @adeneo says, also including some of your current code would help a lot in future questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace `text()` with `html()` if you want the tags to be parsed, not just displayed as text.

```
success: function (data) { 
    $('#level2').html(data.data.content); 
}
```